# FacebookAuthorizationException' with message Unsupported get request - Facebook PHP API

Tags: php, facebook

This url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/389546181070007/feed?access_token={token}&appsecret_proof={secret}&fields=name
```

And:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/186726524843032/feed?access_token={token}&appsecret_proof={secret}&fields=name
```

have both valid pageID's and the same access_token and appsecret. The token I'm getting with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Yet the first one throws an exception and the second one works fine and returns the feed list.

The exception thrown is: **FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported get request.**

Have tried to use a different app and more things... been struggling with this issue for 6 hours now.

Has anyone any idea how it is possible that one page works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to visit the first page on Facebook, I only get “Sorry, this page isn't available”.

That means that either that page is not published yet, or has some access restrictions in place. In both cases, you can not “see” it via API, when you use an app access token.

You will need to use either a page access token for that page, or a user access token for a user that has the right to see the page.